# Whether to use binomial or Poisson distribution, when events are not able to happen continuously, but an average rate is known

Tags: modeling, binomial-distribution, poisson-distribution

Let us say there are on average 15 snowy days in December.

Let $X$ be the number of snowy days in a given December.

Is the binomial distribution, with $X \sim B (31, \frac{15}{31})$, or the Poisson distribution, with $X \sim Po(15)$, correct?

(My argument for the binomial distribution is that there cannot be multiple snowy days in one day.)

Comment: you have answered the question yourself, haven't you?

Comment: @Carlo That's what I thought, but someone told me it was still Poisson, because of something about the peaks of the distributions --- does anyone recognise this?

Comment: This is ia modeling problem. If the choice is only between the binomial and Poisson distributions, go with the former one, because here you must have $P(X\le31)=1$, which is definitely wrong if $X$ has the Poisson distribution.

Comment: Weather patterns tend to last for a while, so binomial is also wrong (if this is real life rather than a homework exercise).

Comment: The fact that you want $P(X \le 31) = 1$ is not really important, because for the Poisson case $P(X > 31)$ is only about $0.00009$.  If the modeling error was that small, it would be a really really good model.